# Max value validation for text field error in laravel

Tags: regex, laravel, validation, rules

I'm trying to validate one of my text field in laravel.

The filed only should accepts numbers(0-9) and the minimum character size is 10. Maximum is 12.

This is my validation rule for the mentioned field,

```
'reload_pin'=>['required','numeric', 'min:10','max:12'],
```

But this gives me an error every time even when I enter a correct input saying

```
input value should not be greater than 12
```

What would be the correct validation and the fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to validate a Numeric value. Therefore it checks for Minimum and Maximum values

In order to validate your input properly you can try this

```
'reload_pin' => 'required|string|min:10|max:12|regex:/[0-9]{9}/'
```

You may refer the laravel documentation for more details [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-size)